# $0 2 5 6 4 1 3$ Multiplied by $5$ Using Trachtenberg (Speed System)

Tags: arithmetic

I have a little problem to applying trachtenberg on this multiplication.

Actually i don't really care with the result (please don't suggest me a calculator), i just want to know how does it work.

We know the answer is :

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&2&5&6&4&1&3\\
  &   &  &  &  &\times&5\\
\hline\\
1&2&8&2&0&6&5
\end{array}$$

The rule said, that

> If we had an odd digit in the multiplicand we would add $5$

And

> If we had an even digit in the multiplicand we would use "the half"
>   (without fraction) of the neighbor in the right side

Then why does digit $5$ become $8$ instead of $0$?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Are you quoting from a particular source whose description you want to understand? Please cite it.

Comment: Actually this is a good method like Vedic Math for do arithmetic named Trachtenberg. I want to learn this to increase my calculating speed. And if it's really works, may be in the future i can teach it to my children.

Comment: Please say more about the method you are using - it is not very clear at all (to me) from your insets what the rule you are referring to is. Perhaps a simpler, understood example in addition to the one you are having trouble understanding?

Comment: I can't explain it well considering my explanation is bad. But what i read is from here https://books.google.co.id/books/about/The_Trachtenberg_Speed_System_of_Basic_M.html?id=ZyqGDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y

Comment: "If we had an odd digit in the multiplicand we would add 5"  Which one is the multiplicand? Where is the odd digit?  We would add 5 to what? If there we have an even digit we would "use the half of the neighbor in the right side"; and do what with it? and what if the neighbor is odd?... Don't assume we know what the trachtenberg is or that we have *any* idea what you are talking about.  ... so, um.... what *ARE* you talking about?  ... Explain *everything* please.

Comment: "I can't explain it well considering my explanation is bad"  THen give us an example.  You got $0256413\times 5 = 1282065$.  Why?  what method did you use?  I'd do 5 times 3 is 15 and carry the 1 and so forth.  You did something else.  What did you do?

Comment: @fleablood Yeah, actually i checked on search page and typing Trachtenberg Method and found 4 or five question about it. So i assume, there must be someone who knows about this. apologize anyway if my question isn't relevant.

Comment: "But what i read is from here books.google.co.id/books/about/… "  Yeah... I'm not going to read an entire book to answer your question.  ... This might come as a surprise to you but people more advanced in math don't always know more about obscure methods than you do.  And you aren't making things easier by assuming things don't need to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.....

It works because $5 = 10\div 2$  So you multiple by $10$ and divide in half.

So we want to do $3$ times $10$ divided by $2$.  So that's $30\div 2$ so we want to write down $\color{blue}15$.  We write down the $5$ but we aren't sure if we will be able to write down the  $\color{blue}1$

Now we go to the next column.  We want to wright down the $\color{blue}1$ from before but we don't know if we can.  We have $\color{red}1$ in this column. We are going to multiply by $10$ and divide in half.  But $\color{red}10$ is an odd number of $10$s and we can't just split it in half and have $0$.  We are going to have a $\color{green}0\color{red}5$.  So we add that $\color{red}5$ to our $\color{blue}1$ and write down $6$.

Now we want to write down the $\color{green}0$.  But can we?

In the next column we have $4$.  We will multiply by $10$ and divide by $2$.  $4$ is even so we will have an even number of $10$s so dividing by $2$ will give us full number of $10$s and that will be $0$. So we don't have to add $5$ to our $\color{green}0$.  We can just write it down.

And so on .....